# replacing NaN values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame. Two of its columns are 'Medicine_ID' and 'Counterfeit_Weight'.

For each value of 'Medicine_ID' there is either NaN or a fixed value in the 'Counterfeit_Weight' column. How do I replace this NaN values with the corresponding fixed value for the particular value of 'Medicine_ID'?

A snippet of my data:

[image]

train_data.loc[train_data['Medicine_ID']=='IXN93'] #for a particular value of 'Medicine_ID'

[image]

Comment: Can you not post your sample data as picture >

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct , you can using `mode`

---

Data Input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Medicine_ID':["A","B","C","D"],'Counterfeit_Weight':[999,2,np.nan,np.nan]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Medicine_ID':["A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"],'Counterfeit_Weight':[2,np.nan,2,np.nan,2,2,np.nan,1,1,2]})
```

---

Solution

```
df1=df1.groupby('Medicine_ID')['Counterfeit_Weight'].apply(lambda x : x.mode()[0]).to_frame()
df=df.merge(df1,left_on='Medicine_ID',right_index=True)
df.Counterfeit_Weight_x.fillna(df.Counterfeit_Weight_y,inplace=True)
df.drop('Counterfeit_Weight_y',1).rename(columns={'Counterfeit_Weight_x':'Counterfeit_Weight'})

Out[360]: 
   Counterfeit_Weight Medicine_ID
0               999.0           A
1                 2.0           B
2                 2.0           C
3                 1.0           D
```

Answer (score 2):

For replace `NaN` by most common value per group `Medicine_ID` is possible use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by first value of `index` after [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefabcdef'),
                   'Counterfeit_Weight':[np.nan,5.0,5.0,np.nan,2.0,4.1,3.0,
                                         np.nan,6.1,np.nan,4.1,4.1],
                   'Medicine_ID':list('caabbbaaabbb')})

print (df)
    A  Counterfeit_Weight Medicine_ID
0   a                 NaN           c
1   b                 5.0           a
2   c                 5.0           a
3   d                 NaN           b
4   e                 2.0           b
5   f                 4.1           b
6   a                 3.0           a
7   b                 NaN           a
8   c                 6.1           a
9   d                 NaN           b
10  e                 4.1           b
11  f                 4.1           b
```

---

```
f = lambda x: x.fillna(0 if x.isnull().all() else x.value_counts().index[0])
df['Counterfeit_Weight'] = (df.groupby('Medicine_ID')['Counterfeit_Weight']
                             .transform(f))
print (df)
    A  Counterfeit_Weight Medicine_ID
0   a                 0.0           c
1   b                 5.0           a
2   c                 5.0           a
3   d                 4.1           b
4   e                 2.0           b
5   f                 4.1           b
6   a                 3.0           a
7   b                 5.0           a
8   c                 6.1           a
9   d                 4.1           b
10  e                 4.1           b
11  f                 4.1           b
```

Comment: train_data['Counterfeit_Weight'] = (train_data.groupby('Medicine_ID')['Counterfeit_Weight']
                             .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().index[0]))) is giving me error

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: I used 

train_data.sort_values(['Medicine_ID','Counterfeit_Weight']).ffill()
 It works well unless some groups of 'Medicine_ID' has value as NaN only for the corresponding 'Counterfeit_Weight' column

Comment: If only NaN for some `Medicine_ID` is possible replace it by `0` ?

Comment: Yes jezraei .. that was the problem when i used sort_values

Comment: yes we can replace it by 0 If only NaN for some Medicine_ID is possible replace it by 0

Comment: OK, I add first row with `c` group which is replaced by 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael. It worked perfectly with my data